# My ruby test cases fail on rake but pass individually. Please help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Some of my ror test cases are passing individually when run using the ruby command. But when I run on rake, they fail. This is happening specifically on db2. I need some help on the same.

Comment: The test case does not throw any error. The assertion just fails. But the same passes when I run as 'ruby test/functional/controller_name.rb' . This behavior is specific to db2. When I run rake on oracle setup, the same test cases pass. Is there a way I can debug this issue?

Comment: Can you verify that between each test your database gets cleared in the teardown step?

Comment: Does your rake-call execute only one test file or multiple? Once I had the problem, that one of me tests required something, what influenced another test.

Comment: Hi knut, I am calling multiple files. And none of the test cases are dependent on each other.

Comment: Bert:  Seems to be calling. I gave some debug statements there and they are being called. But how do I verify if the database is being cleared? Give some count of any table?

Comment: Can you post your failing test? I've seen this before, although what our problem was escapes my mind at the moment.

Comment: the failures are simple assertions. It's nothing significant. It seems as if the required fixture is not loaded or something similar. This is happening specifically on db2.

Comment: I found out why some of the failures where there on rake. One issue was that my tables where being populated by sequence numbers. This resulted in duplicate ids in tables as some ids were already present in the fixtures. Hence while fetching, the fetched order was purely based on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer after some digging.
The problem was that I was trying to assert the results of a find on a model object.
Now internally, this find translates into a select query on the database.
Unfortunately, oracle/db2 do not guarantee the order of the select fetch.

In many test cases, I was asserting the first/second/third etc element of the array returned by the find statement. The problem here is, the index of zero of the array  might contain a different value as the select might return in a different order.

So either, use a order by clause or sort the resultant array and then assert.

I still have some failures on db2, but then, the number has drastically come down.

Cheers!